# Appending a new line in a previous created text file in java

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader, file-handling, bufferedwriter

I am in trouble finding how to read a text file and then write a new line after the ones that were before on the file.

Like (current file)

1234 Albert

(edited file)

1234 Albert

1223 Dave

for this, i am using this code without success.

```
   String suma="";
   String verify="";

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Beto\\Desktop\\registrocuentas.txt"));

        BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Beto\\Desktop\\registrocuentas.txt")); 
        while((verify=br.readLine())!=null){
            suma=suma+" "+verify;
            System.out.println(suma);
        }
        suma=suma+" "+cuenta+"."+nombre+apellidoPaterno+apellidoMaterno;
        String split[]=suma.split(" ");
        int c=split.length;
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
            bw.write(split[i]);
        }
        bw.close();
        br.close();
```

Currently the edited file erases the old entry, making the file looks like this

(current result of my code for edited file)

1223 Dave

Comment: Try to use a Debugger to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the append method instead of write:

```
bw.append(split[i]);
```

This adds to the file with existing data, while `write` completely erases the old data and puts new one in.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). They tell you how to use BufferedWriters.

When you create your FileWriter, use this line instead of your current one:

```
BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Beto\\Desktop\\registrocuentas.txt"), true);
```

This means you want to append to your file.